# Dynamic styles using tailwind JIT compiler not working bit src tailwind environment

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, jit, tailwind-3, bit.dev

I have couple of react components created in bit src sope with tailwind environment.([bit src](https://bit.dev/) , [tailwind environment](https://bit.cloud/learn-bit-react/ui-library-wrappers/tailwind/environments/env-with-tailwind) ).

Its working fine with following variations.

1. built in classes i.e. w-0 w-1 w-2 w-4 ...
2. Pre define values i.e. w-[24px] bg-[#123456] ...

Its Not working with dynamic values provided by variable in run time as following. Throwing error saying `CssSyntaxError (1:0) D:\Auzmor\office_component_library\node_modules\@auzmorui\component-library.tailwind.environments.env-with-tailwind\dist\tailwind\<no source> Unknown word`

```
const width = 24
<div classname={`w-[${width}px]`}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: ['component-library/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {}
}
```

Tailwind version
`"tailwindcss": "3.1.6"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a few days ago we finished the implementation of Tailwind with the new Bit environments ([more info](https://bit.dev/blog/migrate-to-new-component-development-environments-lfhd699k/)).

This Env supports Tailwind v3 by default and you won't have problems with the JIT engine as the Env loads the Tailwind CDN in development (`bit start`).

You can find the source for this new Env here https://new.bit.cloud/learnbit-react/tailwind/tailwind-env

---

Anyway, as far as I know the implementation you are trying to use is not correct. Tailwind doesn't support building class names dynamically https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

The correct one should be something like this:

```
const widths = {
  '24': 'w-[24px]',
  '32': 'w-[32px]',
  '48': 'w-[48px]',
  '64': 'w-[64px]',
  '96': 'w-[96px]',
};
    
<div className={`${widths['24']} bg-red-500`}>24px</div>
```